# How to make a box-shadow inset with a transparency?

Tags: html, css

I'm interested in learning how to create a css3 box-shadow inset with a transparency.

See the input in the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TeGkt/4/

For the input's background image. How can you create that effect without needing an image?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using CSS3 styles:
http://jsfiddle.net/arnorhs/Nz7KG/

Will not work in IE pre ie9

And I didn't add any of -moz or -webkit- prefixes for compatibility..

I also didn't do it 100% the same. Your question seemed to be towards if it's possible or not...

Comment: Possibly use a CSS3 gradient to create the proper colors?

Answer (score 1):

```
rgba(255,255,255,0.75)
```

where `rgba(r,g,b,a)` is red green blue alpha